# clock skew was detected warning

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am logging into a laptop via teamviewer and then ssh- ing into another system. When I run `catkin_make`   in that system, it gives me the warning:

```
clock skew was detected. Your build may be incomplete.
```

What is the reason for this warning; Is it due to teamviewer? How can this be avoided.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244124/clock-skew-was-detected-warning/) by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This isn't related to ROS; it's actually a message from make, when it's running the build files generated by cmake.

Stack overflow has a [decent explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824500/compiling-c-on-remote-linux-machine-clock-skew-detected-warning).

It seems like you're connecting through quite a few machines. If you're transferring files between machines or using a network filesystem, it's possible that not all of the computers involved agree on what time it is. (possibly disagreeing on which time zone you're in or whether use local time or UTC for timestamps)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2